# Automate sending info to the blockchain once an specific number of entries is reached?

Tags: solidity

It's a music website, the idea is to record on the blockchain every time a song is played.

Since we don't want to force users to install metamask so they can sign transactions, the idea is to store in an array, so that the smart contract sends it to the blockchain every 100 plays for example.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please explain better, what technology do you use for your website? .net asp?
when you say "send to the blockchain" do you mean to a smart contract?
and an array of what do you want to send?

If you want to send something from a website to a smart contract on the blockchain you can use Nethereum thru .net asp.
Shouldn't be hard to write a c# code to send something every X times.

Just remember that storing new data on the blockchain cost gas (money).